# How To hide and show fields according to value from check box on edit page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am Having a page in which i should hide or show fields like 1 dropdown and 1 text box by the value from a radio button. Its working fine in the AddUser page but when  editing the User, at that time it is not working . Can some one help me how to check a condition on page load itself

```
<label class="form>
        Active
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsActive, true, new { onclick = "Hide()" })


        </label>
   <label class="form">
      InActive
     @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsActive, false, new { onclick="Show()"})


          </label>

function Hide()
    {
        $('#Reasondiv').hide();
    }
    function Show()
    {
        $('#Reasondiv').show();
    }
```

while Loading the edit page itself i need to check whether the IsActive is true or false so that according to it I can show or hide the divs

Comment: `var isActive - @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.IsActive)` will get you the value. Then you can just use `if (isActive) { ... } else { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JQuery approach you need to modify your HTML a bit and need to add few more lines of code as follows for edit page:

HTML:

```
<label class="form ActiveRadioContainer">
        Active
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsActive, true, new { onclick = "Hide()" })
        </label>
<label class="form InActiveRadioContainer">
      InActive
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsActive, false, new { onclick="Show()"})
</label>
```

added separate classes as `ActiveRadioContainer` and `InActiveRadioContainer` and then addition JQuery code needed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var isActive = $(".ActiveRadioContainer input[type=radio]").is(":checked");

    if(isActive){
        $('#Reasondiv').hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#Reasondiv').show();
    }
});
```